# What does 'Maytey' mean in John Clare's poem?

Tags: meaning, definition

What is the meaning of 'Maytey' in John Clare's poem titled 'To an April Daisy'?

It starts with the line, which is "Welcome old Maytey peeping once again."

Does it mean 'mate' in a familiar style?

Comment: The full OED doesn't include ***maytey***. My guess is it's a "poetic pun" drawing on colloquial ***mate = matey = pal = chum = friend = [comrade](http://www.johnclare.info/flindex.html)*** AND the month of May (the poem is actually called [*To an April Daisy*](https://johnclare.blogspot.com/2012/04/)), plus perhaps a nod towards ***may-flower***. But that's just my ***guess*** - the question itself is inherently Off Topic, since any answers can only really be "opinions".

Comment: This is apparently from the period 1822-1837, and so **maytey** might have been in regular use. His poetry also contains the words **blest** and **kye**.